# ID from insert with multiple rows

Tags: mysql

Is it safe to assume that the auto increment id from a insert with multiple rows will be incremented by one starting to the `mysql_last_insert_id()` value? Could there be a concurrent insert (from an other user session) between this multiple insert?

In this example `tbl_name` has an autoincrement field called `id`:

```
INSERT INTO tbl_name (a,b,c) VALUES(1,2,3),(4,5,6),(7,8,9);

$nbAffectedRows = mysql_affected_rows();
$idFirstRowInserted = mysql_last_insert_id();

$arrayId = array();
if($nbAffectedRows &gt; 0){
    for($i = 0; $i &lt;= $nbAffectedRows; $i++){
        $arrayId[] = $idFirstRowInserted + $i;
    }
}
```

Will `$arrayId` always contain values incremented by one correponding to the 'id' of the rows inserted ?

Comment: One thing you should check is auto_increment_increment, which specifies whether MySQL increments by 1 or another number: `show variables like 'auto_increment_increment';`

Comment: Thanks for the information. I checked it and the value is 1 (the deault value).

Answer (score 1):

It will be safe to assume that, if you wrap your `INSERT`s in a transaction. As a side effect your query will run faster too.

Comment: Do you mean by creating a queue?

Comment: I've just read more on auto_inc with InnoDB, it appears there's `AUTO_INC lock` that is `..kept to the end of current SQL statement`.  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-auto-increment-handling.html So your query should be safe by itself

Comment: Thanks for your time German Rumm. Unfortunately, I'm using MyISAM tables.

Comment: From http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id "The ID that was generated is maintained in the server on a per-connection basis.(...) This behavior ensures that each client can retrieve its own ID without concern for the activity of other clients, and without the need for locks or transactions."